# .NET Framework 1.1 on IIS 7

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp.net, .net

I have inherited a .NET Framework 1.1 web site that I must host with IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008. I'm having some trouble.

### 1. Installation

I installed .NET Framework 1.1 following [these instructions](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/472/how-to-install-aspnet-11-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008/).

The installation automatically created a new Application Pool "ASP.NET 1.1". I use that.

### 2. Trouble

When I launch the web site I see web.config runtime errors:

> The  tag contains an invalid value for the 'culture' attribute.

I fix that one and then see:

> Child nodes are not allowed.

I don't want to keep playing this whack-a-mole game. **Something must be wrong.**

### 3. Am I sure this is .NET 1.1?

I examine the automatically created application pool. I see that it's 1.1.

Advanced Settings...

[image: Automatic AppPool .NET 1.1 Advanced]

Basic Settings...

[image: Automatic AppPool .NET 1.1 Basic]

This doesn't seem right.

While 1.1 is set, it's not an option in the Advanced drop down selectors.

And why in the Basic box is it just "v1.1" and not ".NET Framework v1.1.4322"? That would be more consistent.

### 4. I cannot create other .NET 1.1 App Pools

I cannot select .NET Framework 1.1 for other application pools. It's not an option in the drop down selectors. What's up with that?

[image: App Pool missing .NET 1.1 option]

### What now?

- Why isn't v1.1 an option for all AppPools?
- How can I verify my application is in fact using .NET Framework 1.1?
- Why might I get these runtime errors?

Comment: This is a cross post of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502081/net-framework-1-1-on-iis-7 and is discouraged..

Answer (score 1):

Windows 2008 doesn't have .NET 1.1 installed.  You can [manually install .NET 1.1](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/02/installing-asp-net-1-1-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008.aspx).